# Combine ActiveRecord::Result in .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I have this working currently but there must be a better way. I have a model where I query an external oracle DB view. In this particular case I have to run one query per id value and combine these results into an array.

This works but, it requires quite a bit of maintenance on the Array to get the information in an easier to use format. Hopefully there is a way to simplify this:

```
def self.count_by_year(ids, year)
    start_date = DateTime.strptime(year.to_s, "%Y").strftime("%Y%m%d")
    end_date = DateTime.strptime(year.to_s, "%Y").end_of_year.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    bulk_issues = []
    if ids.size > 1
      ids.each do |uc|
        bulk_issues << (External.connection.select_all "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB WHERE ID='#{uc.id}' AND GROUP_NAME != 'CA' AND STATUS != 'Cancelled' AND (DATE_OPENED BETWEEN '#{start_date}' AND '#{end_date}')")
      end
    else
      bulk_issues << (External.connection.select_all "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB WHERE ID='#{ids.first.id}' AND GROUP_NAME != 'CA' AND STATUS != 'Cancelled' AND (DATE_OPENED BETWEEN '#{start_date}' AND '#{end_date}')")
    end
    return bulk_issues
  end
```

When called this returns the following:

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Result:0x007fdafd95ec20 @columns=["count(*)"], @rows=[[51]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={}>, #<ActiveRecord::Result:0x007fdafd95d320 @columns=["count(*)"], @rows=[[19]], @hash_rows=nil, @column_types={}>]
```

When flattened it returns:

```
[{"count(*)"=>51}, {"count(*)"=>19}]
```

Which is a pain to pull the data out of since I have to pull the values out and put them into a new array for it to be formatted for what I am using the values for.

What I am trying to do is get the function to return the data in a array as follows:

```
[51, 19]
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to be extra careful when making raw queries to avoid injecting anything harmful in your query. Using placeholders makes these significantly safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for a start, [Oracle supports `IN` expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm), so instead of your `ids.each...` just do:

```
bulk_issues = External.connection.select_all "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DB WHERE ID IN (#{ids.map{|id| "'#{id.id}'"}.join(",")}) AND GROUP_NAME != 'CA' AND STATUS != 'Cancelled' AND (DATE_OPENED BETWEEN '#{start_date}' AND '#{end_date}')"
```

So then this won't be an array, it'll just be a hash like `{"count(*)"=>70}`, so to get just `70` out of that call:

```
*, count = bulk_issues.first
```

So adding an `AS` to your query so we can be sure what our hash will return, your whole method becomes:

```
def self.count_by_year(ids, year)
  start_date = DateTime.strptime(year.to_s, "%Y").strftime("%Y%m%d")
  end_date = DateTime.strptime(year.to_s, "%Y").end_of_year.strftime("%Y%m%d")

  res = External.connection.select_all("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM DB WHERE ID IN (#{ids.map{|id| "'#{id.id}'"}.join(",")}) AND GROUP_NAME != 'CA' AND STATUS != 'Cancelled' AND (DATE_OPENED BETWEEN '#{start_date}' AND '#{end_date}')")

  return res.to_hash.first['count'].to_i
end
```

Comment: thank you! I'll give it a shot shortly and report back